# Locally hosted website live chat

Tags: chat

I am looking for a website chat system (paid or free) which can be hosted locally rather than through an online service. This tool is going to be used as part of a company intranet system allowing staff to communicate with members of the service desk through 1:1 chat window, which will be accessible through the intranet.

Ideally the software would need to be PHP or Javascript based since it needs to be integrated into Umbraco, which seems somewhat fussy, but I will take recommendations which don't fall into this criteria.

I have tried looking at phplivesupport, which seemed to be what I was looking for. The main issue with this was getting in touch with the company. Since support would be preferable I would like the software to still be relatively active with development/support.

Comment: How would you want to use that? Do you want to have a 1:1 chat? A 1:n streaming tool? If you tell more about your actual situation a proper solution is easier to be found.

Answer (score 3):

Try Microsoft Lync.

Lync Basic 2013 gives you instant messaging (IM), audio and video calls, Lync Meetings, availability (presence) information, and sharing capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

We here at Click4Assistance typically host the software on our own servers, however we do have customers hosting the software on their servers. Our script is a small piece of html / JavaScript and is easy to implement. If you wish to discuss this our team will be more than happy to help answer any questions you have, our contact details can be found [on our website](http://www.click4assistance.co.uk/)